# How to call an async function from other file with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

I have 2 files:

```js
// index.js

export async function main(){
  // Here is a set of functions with which
  // I get an array with different data. these functions
  // are also asynchronous, so you should use
  // "wait"; and hence this function is also
  // async. That array is the "resultado" variable.
  return Promise.resolve(resultado.join("\n"));
}
```

```js
// App.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { main } from './Backend/index'; 

export default function App() {
  const [someVal, setSomeVal] = useState('');
  (async () => {
    const awaitedVal = await main()
    setSomeVal(awaitedVal)
  })();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        <a> {someVal} </a>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

As it is, it doesn't work (because being the function asynchronous, it doesn't work like that). I have two different files. How do I do it?

**UPDATED:** Now, a new error appears.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVfY8.png)

Comment: i haven't tried it but a possible solution can be adding a ```[val,setVal ]= setState()``` then put set state inside an async IIFE and await for main to set the state with it

Answer (score 0):

main() returns a promise which is not resolved and react can not show it's value. what you can do is to add a useState hook and put that between curly braces.

Then inside an async IIFE set value of useState to result of awaited main()

This is App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react'
import { main } from './main';
function App() {
  const [someVal, setSomeVal] = useState('');
  (async () => {
    const awaitedVal = await main()
    setSomeVal(awaitedVal)
  })();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          {someVal} Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Instead of async, await and IIFE you can also use `.then`

```
main().then(res => {
    setSomeVal(res)
  })
```

And this is main.js

```
export async function main() {
    return Promise.resolve("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now, no error appears; but it doesn't show any data. It shows a blank screen, as if it is not receiving any data

Comment: Can you update your question with your implementation and possible errors ?

Comment: yes, 1 minute...

Comment: The post is updated.

Comment: @ExpErgio the implementation has a flaw it should be like this :
```
(async () => {
    const awaitedVal = await main()
    setSomeVal(awaitedVal)
}
)();
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        <h2> {someVal} </h2>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
  } 
```

Comment: check my answer again, you don't need to wrap the return inside iife

Comment: Changed. And now, there is other error. I update the initial post with the new image and the updated code

Comment: Check if `return Promise.resolve('Some Text');` in index.js gives you correct result if it does you should debug `index.js` otherwise you need to play with it a little bit and check without anchor tags inside <Text>  and with constant text. i haven't used React Native a lot I'm reactjs developer